# matlab 2016a simulink graph legend

Tags: matlab, graph, legend, simulink

I have a question about matlab simulink:

**Notice** just Matlab **2016a** simulink because of in old version i can do it but in 2016 version i can't change or set new legend to scope graphs.
help me to do it please.

Thank you

Comment: What is graph in simulink? Do you mean scope?

Comment: yes i mean scope output's graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2016b, so I'm not sure I can solve your problem at 100%, but I can give you some examples how to set current names for legend.

1. First of all turn on the legend property: Scope\View\Legend

   Now we can see legend but it has default names. Lets change it!
2. First method - I can just double left click on it and change it's names. But it is not really good - I can put any signal name even if there is no such names in the simulink model.
3. We can assign any names to signals in the model:[image]
4. Another method is to give current names to your blocks - scope shows that names by default. [image] It is informative (so and previous method) because we can easily see where this signal comes from.

Maybe it is what you want.

Comment: thank you so much. it was helpful and solved my problem. it needed to double click on legend as you said that.